# Weird behaviour while converting to realRatingMatrix

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I have a data frame which has 3 columns. first two are factors and third one is numeric. I'm just selecting data from rows 1230 to row 1250. The data is as follows

```
> beer_ratings[1230:1250,]
     beer_beerid review_profilename review_overall
1230       52211           WITTBEER            4.0
1231       52211         orbitalr0x            3.0
1232       52211        ColForbinBC            3.5
1233       52211         Heatwave33            4.0
1234       52211       StlHopHead77            4.0
1235       52211         AleWatcher            5.0
1236       52211         scruffwhor            4.0
1237       52211           polisanl            1.5
1238       52211         VncentLIFE            4.0
1239       52211             ahq514            3.5
1240       52211            SpdKilz            4.0
1241       52211            oline73            4.0
1242       52211     TheGordianKnot            3.0
1243       52211        homebrew311            4.0
1244       52211         ZeroSignal            4.0
1245       52211           drcarver            4.0
1246       52211         jzeilinger            4.0
1247       52211           JayS2629            4.0
1248       52211          superspak            4.0
1249       52211         AleWatcher            3.5
1250       52211          shortbus7            3.5
```

Now I convert this to a realRatingMatrix and try to get a summary of the ratings

```
a<- as(beer_ratings[1230:1250,],"realRatingMatrix")
summary(getRatings(a))
```

Oddly, the summary is as follows

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.500   3.500   4.000   3.925   4.000   8.500
```

Why is it showing max as 8.5?

I'm using recommenderlab library

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. User AleWatcher has rated the same beer twice with 5 and 3.5.